# How to allow Java applications (Umlet) to access OneDrive files on Mac?

Tags: mac, java, onedrive

I'm fond of this little program: https://www.umlet.com/ . Never had issue with running it on Windows.
Recently at work I have to use it on a Mac, and if I try to save/open a diagram in a OneDrive folder synced by Microsoft OneDrive sync client, the open/save dialog does not show any files in the OneDrive folder.
I suspect this has something to do with granting permissions to access OneDrive files, but I can't find any options anywhere to allow this. Any solution?

Comment: The OneDrive folder is no different than any other folder on your Mac.  Can you see files in other folders?

Comment: @Allan, I can see files in normal folders, but browsing OneDrive folder shows no files.

Comment: Does that Java app use a certain file extension when opening/saving files?

Comment: it uses .uxf file extension.

Comment: Is there a selection for “All files?”